# Showing data from database using Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I'm quite new to Laravel and what I am trying to achieve is to display some string from my data to a page. I'm using Eloquent Model and I can't figure out what I do wrong here. I've attached some of my code below. I hope I make it clear enough.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
    
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('products.index')->with('products', $products);
    }
```

Here's where I want the data to be displayed.

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section ('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        @if(count($products) > 1 )
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>{{$product->prod_name}}</h3>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>No product found</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

**UPDATED: The problem is with my loop logic**
Since I have only one item inside my database, my loop is supposed to be **>= 1** instead of **> 1**

```
@if(count($products) >= 1 )
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <div class="well">
            <h3>{{$product->prod_name}}</h3>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <p>No product found</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Is there any error? or what is the exact problem that you're facing? Please mention it in the post.

Comment: Please copy over the actual code instead of images of the code. It helps with SEO, readability and availability.

Comment: can you try @if($products->count() > 1) and see if that makes any difference. Failing that, echo $products->count(), just to confirm you actually have some products.

Comment: @Flame Hi, sorry! I have now updated the post with the actual code, instead of pictures.

Comment: @Aashishgaba The problem is I cannot loop through a table to get data and get it to display on a view page.

Comment: @Aashishgaba I tried using dd($products) in the controller and it shows that the data is fetched, but the problem might be at the form where I want my data to be shown.

Comment: You can simplify your view by simply using `@if($products->count())`. The `count()` here is a function of the collection object that you actually have (`$products`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix up your code and use the correct approach.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
    
        $products = Product::all();

        return view('products.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Notice how I've passed an array via `compact` as the 2nd parameter of the `view` function. You can also use `view('products.index', ['products' => $products])`, I just prefer compact as it is cleaner.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Products</h1>

        @if(!$products->isEmpty())
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>{{ $product->prod_name }}</h3>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>No products found.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

Notice how I've made use of `isEmpty`, which checks if a collection (obtained here from Eloquent) is empty or not.

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to fix my code now by fixing the loop section, but I'd appreciate the good practice regarding how to go about the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of with() maybe View::share can work.

```
$products = Product::all();
View::share('$products',$products);
return view('products.index');
```

And dont forget to import View class from Facades. Put this at the begining of page

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

Comment: You tend to use view:share() when you want to make data available to all views, I don't think this will make any difference